# Calculate complex expression with the Cdo package in python

Tags: python

I have a netcdf file with variables tas and hurs. I want to use the expr operator of the Cdo python package to calculate a new variable h. The formula of h is:

```
h=5/9 * (e-10), where
e = 6.112 * 10^(7.5*tas/(237.7+tas))*hurs/100
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `python-cdo` is just a wrapper of `cdo` so I'd suggest you using `cdo` first and then translate it into the python wrapper version (if you really need it...).

I think that writing exactly the same formula as input to the `expr` operator should work. If you check the documentation `*`, `+`, `/` and `^` are all valid operators and you only need to supply the input variables for the expression using the variable names from the netcdf file `infile`.

```bash
cdo expr,’out=(5/9)*((6.112 * 10^(7.5*tas/(237.7+tas))*hurs/100)-10);’ infile outfile
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:Error in calling operator expr with:
>>> /usr/bin/cdo -O -s -expr,h=(5/9)*((6.112 * 10^(7.5*tas/(237.7+tas))*hurs/100)-10); temp.nc datasets/humidity_index/rcp_2_6/mohc_hadgem2_es_r1i1p1_smhi_rca4/humidex_rcp26_MOHC-HadGEM2-ES_SMHI-RCA4_r1i1p1_20160101-20251230.nc<<<
STDOUT:
STDERR:/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: This syntax error seems clear: you have an unexpected bracket, so check your brackets

Comment: The brackets seem fine. I copy pasted the expression you provided.

Comment: you don't have any quote surrounding the formula